# Issue loading next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, progress-bar, progress

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.initial_layout);

    // progress bar
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                pbHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(70);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (pb.getProgress() >= 95) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(initialActivity.this,startingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

My goal is to automatically load next activity when the progress bar finishes loading without firing any other event , but i cant seem to do that. I guess somethings wrong with the Thread , i am a begginer. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define custom interface which give you call back when progress is complete :

```
public interface OnProgressFinishListener{
    public void onProgressFinish();
}
```

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to update progress :

```
public void startProgress(final OnProgressFinishListener onProgressFinishListener){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer>(){
      @Override
      protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
          while (progressStatus < 100) {
                 progressStatus += 1;
                 publishProgress(progressStatus);

                 try {
                      Thread.sleep(70);
                 }catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                 }
          }
          return progressStatus;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
         super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         pb.setProgress(values[0]);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Integer progress) {
         super.onPostExecute(progress);
         if(progress==100){
            onProgressFinishListener.onProgressFinish();
         }
      }
   }.execute();
}
```

How to implement custom interface :

```
pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
startProgress(new OnProgressFinishListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressFinish() {
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Progress Finish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You have to start the activity from the main thread. Consider executing the runnable from a handler. ` Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                pbHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(70);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (pb.getProgress() >= 95) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(initialActivity.this,startingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        }
    },1000);
return;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pb.getProgress() >= 95) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(initialActivity.this,startingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
```

above code in incorrect

```
if (pb.getProgress() >= 95) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(context,startingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
```

store the context on the current activity in the member variable of activity;

```
 public Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

even a better solution is to use AsynTask

example

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

Comment: Unfortunately , null has stopped